# How to exclude auto-configuration from Spring Boot WebMvcTest

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-cloud-consul

I am trying to implement a Spring Boot Mock MVC unit test and would like to exclude the spring-cloud-consul auto configuration to avoid requiring connectivity to a remote service.

It looks like I should be able to achieve this with the below:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(value = MyController.class, excludeAutoConfiguration = ConsulAutoConfiguration.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc(addFilters = false, printOnlyOnFailure = false)
```

However this still appears to be trying to connect to remote Consul as I am unable to run this unit test when offline.

```
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to consul.****:8500 [consul.****/**.**.**.**] failed: connect timed out
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:150)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:380)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
```

If I add the -Ddebug to the unit test run configuration I am not seeing this listed in the exclusions:

```
Positive matches:
-----------------

ConsulAutoConfiguration matched:
      - AllNestedConditions 2 matched 0 did not; NestedCondition on ConditionalOnConsulEnabled.OnConsulEnabledCondition.FoundClass @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'com.ecwid.consul.v1.ConsulClient'; @ConditionalOnMissingClass did not find unwanted class; NestedCondition on ConditionalOnConsulEnabled.OnConsulEnabledCondition.FoundProperty @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.cloud.consul.enabled) matched (ConditionalOnConsulEnabled.OnConsulEnabledCondition)

Exclusions:
-----------

    None
```

I am wondering if this is because this config is loaded at bootstrap time?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to find a work around by adding the following annotation to the test.

```
@TestPropertySource(properties="spring.cloud.consul.enabled=false")
```